# how to align vertical table to horizontal view in PHP

Tags: php, ms-access

I have manage to query a table in MS Access DB using PDO with PHP programming.
But the table displayed in vertical view. I want to change it to normal table but I don't know how.

Here is my code :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
        $month = $_POST['month'];
        $year = $_POST['year'];

        $connectdb = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=D:\Demo2018.mdb; Uid=; Pwd=COMPLETEPAYROLL;");

        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM `tblPAyTrans` 
                WHERE Month ='$month' AND Year ='$year'";

        if ($result = $connectdb->query($sql)) {
            echo '<table>';
            foreach($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {                
                foreach($row as $key  => $value) {
                    echo '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>';
                }
            }
            echo '</table>';
        }      
    }
?>
```

The output look like this :

```
| AutoNumber    |<-column
| 39779         |<-value
| Employee ID   |<-column
| 1008          |<-value
| Salary Type   |<-column
| Monthly       |<-value
| Pay Frequency |<-column
| Once a Month  |<-value
```

The output that I want :

```
|Column Name|Column Name|Column Name|Column Name|
|   Value   |   Value   |   Value   |   Value   |
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show us sample data which would result in _more_ than one of expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `foreach` with below code

```
$rows = '';
foreach($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {                
    $heading = '';
    $rows .= '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $key  => $value) {
        $heading .= '<th>'.$key.'</th>';
        $rows .= '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
    }
    $rows .= '</tr>';
}
echo '<tr>'.$heading.'</tr>';
echo $rows;
```

Comment: It did works but the column name repeatedly adding after the end of the column name of my table.

Comment: @Richmond - can you please share screenshot for this

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/c2sUq8) - code
[link](https://ibb.co/mAU9q8) - output

Comment: @Richmond - put `$heading` before 2nd `foreach` as per my code. Also, put do same for `<tr>`